# How to Pass a Child Class into a method requiring Super Class as parameter

Tags: java

So I'm learning Java and I've got an interface method that requires a super class as a parameter. I'd like to to pass the child class as the parameter. Anyone know of an easy way to do this. The parent class is from an animation library I'm using and created my own child class from it.

For example:

```
public class B extends A {

    public void UpdateAnimation() {
        final Interface intefaceMethod = new Interface() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(//**How to pass child class?**//) {
                //child class stuff to do at end of animation
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to restrict the parameter to _only_ the subclass type?

Comment: I'm trying to override the method to accept the subclass, so that I can adjust variables that are only in the subclass. If I don't override it, the method can only access variables for the super class.

Answer (score 2):

You just pass it as:

```
onAnimationEnd(childClass);
```

It's the definition of polymorphism, children must be able to act as their parents.

From the Java API you can for example see this in `paintComponent()` method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;    
}
```

Even though `Graphics` is declared parameter from old times, now `Graphics2D` object (which extends `Graphics` class) is given, but unless you cast it like this it would act as `Graphics` object.

Comment: But changing the method's parameters to a different type will count as a new instance of the method would it not? Therefore, it would no longer be an override of the Super class's method, and thus the method calls in the super class would not be utilizing the new method. Unless I'm just not looking at this the right way.

Comment: @user3092678 That's correct, you cannot change the definition of overriden method. But I though your problem was passing a child object to an already defined method with parent parameter.

Comment: It is my problem, the Parent class utilizes the interface which takes the parent class as the parameter. The method is designed to be overridden so you can perform the actions you need. However, the actions I need are variables within the Child class. I need to be able to override the method with my child class and/or somehow access my child classes variables with the overridden method.