# Passing superclasses into a method where a subclass is needed

Tags: java, oop

Ok, while I tried to find a title that explains the problem I probably have to expand on it.

Recently I implemented a small program that will be used to control a tape library. Knowing it had to work with multiple different types of tape library so the following design was developed.

```
interface Tapelibrary<T extends TapeDrive> {
    List<T> getListofDrives();
    void doSomethingWithDrive(T d);
}

class SpecificTapeLibrary implements Tapelibrary<HPDrive> {
    private List<HPDrive> driveList;

    SpecificTapeLibrary() {
        driveList.add(new HPDrive());
        driveList.add(new HPDrive());
        driveList.add(new HPDrive());
    }

    @Override
    public List<HPDrive> getListofDrives() {
      return driveList;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomethingWithDrive(HPDrive d) {
       d.doSomethingHPspecific();
    }
}

abstract class TapeDrive {
    void doSomething() {
    }
}

class HPDrive extends TapeDrive {
    void doSomethingHPspecific() {
    }
}
```

The correct tape library is determined by a factory based on command line arguments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tapelibrary<? extends TapeDrive> t = new TapeLibraryFabric().get();
    List<? extends TapeDrive> listOfDrives = t.getListofDrives();

    // the user selects a drive by using a small UI or something
    TapeDrive selectedDrive = listOfDrives.get(0);

    t.doSomethingWithDrive(selectedDrive); // compiler error
}
```

This does make sense since the compiler would have to explicitly cast the supertype TapeDrive to the subtype HPDrive which is expected by the doSomethingWithDrive(HPDrive) methods in SpecificTapeLibrary

How would this be solved in a good oop way? I ended up not using generics and casting inside the doSomethingWithDrive method (as suggested here:[How to Pass a Child Class into a method requiring Super Class as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531533/how-to-pass-a-child-class-into-a-method-requiring-super-class-as-parameter)). But that can't be the optimal solution.

While writing this post another solution popped into my head which is much cleaner. The DriveSelector class encapsulates the selection process.

```
class DriveSelector {
    <T> T selectDrive(List<T> inputList) {
        // give the user an UI or something to select a drive 
        return inputList.get(0);
    }
}

// the tape library then uses the selector
public void doSomethingWithSelectedDrive(DriveSelector selector) {
     HPDrive t = selector.selectDrive(driveList);
     t.doSomethingHPspecific();
}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: why "does class SpecificTapeLibrary implements Tapelibrary<HPDrive>" need HPDrive instead of TapeDrive?

Comment: Your `DriveSelector` class isn't useful: you get exactly the same from it as if you invoke `inputList.get(0)` directly.

Comment: @efekctive - The idea was that a non-abstract (that is a real world tape library) has to have a non-abstract drive build into it. I may see another flaw there because it would mean that a tape library always has one type of drive build into it which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all of your work in a generic method:

```
static <T extends TapeDrive> void doStuff(Tapelibrary<T> t) {
  List<T> listOfDrives = t.getListofDrives();

  // the user selects a drive by using a small UI or something
  T selectedDrive = listOfDrives.get(0);

  t.doSomethingWithDrive(selectedDrive);
}
```

Then call this from your main method:

```
Tapelibrary<? extends TapeDrive> t = new TapeLibraryFabric().get();
doStuff(t);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/k43QXx)

The way this works is that it removes all of the wildcards - the thing about wildcards is that the compiler treats every one as different, even if the values are derived from a single generic instance. By putting things into the generic method like this, you allow the compiler to know that all of the `T`s are the same type - thus it can know that the calls are safe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I got it.